# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) while httpPost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-post

i tried to call C# function through angular
 i saw a template how to do it and i got this error.
 o tried to look for a solution in google but it is kind pf general problem.
i am pretty sure that i did not adapt my code properly 
this is the javascript code:

```
 var app = angular.module("loginApp", []);
    app.controller("loginC", ['$scope', '$http',function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.login = function () {
           // $http.post('/login.aspx/Login', { userName: $scope.vm.username, password: $scope.vm.password });
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'login.aspx/Login',                    
                data: { userName: $scope.vm.username, password: $scope.vm.password }
            }
            $http(httpreq).success(function (response) {

                alert("Saved successfully.");
            })
        };



    }]);
```

this is the C# function declaration(this function reside in login code behind file):

```
 protected void Login(String userName,String password)
{
 //some code
}
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the HTTP's configuration by adding "headers" to  httpreq variable

```
var httpreq = {
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/login.aspx/Login',
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'},                     
                data: { username: $scope.vm.username, password: $scope.vm.password }
            }
            $http(httpreq).success(function () {

                alert("Saved successfully.");
            })
```

the error is gone and the alert is poped up , but i put BP at the  beginning of the function in server side and i still cannot reach there,

i already tried to add [webmethod] and [HttpPost]  decorate.

**UPDATE2**

when i changed the URL to

```
url: 'login.aspx'
```

(without the function name) and i set a BP at the PageLoad function ,i succeeded  to reach the BP at the server side that mean the problem is with the path to the function.
what can i do?

Comment: seeing as this is a 500 (server-side) error, we'll need to see the server-side (C#) code

Comment: ן wrote the function's declaration, this is the whole code

Comment: if that's truly "the whole code", then the problem should be apparent -- it's not doing anything at all

Comment: i really ask what does it matter ? i set a BP at the beginning of the function and it fails before

Comment: at the moment i have just " response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); " to check if i reach this BP

Comment: try it by making your method `[WebMethod]`

Comment: @TejinderSingh  
i already tried it , i have some progress , do you have any idea now?

Comment: @YonatanAmir share your C# code here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var httpreq = {
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/login.aspx/Login',
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'},                     
                data: { userName: $scope.vm.username, password: $scope.vm.password }
            }
            $http(httpreq).success(function () {

                alert("Saved successfully.");
            })


 [WebMethod]
 [HttpPost]
 protected static void Login(String userName,String password)
{
 //some code
}
```

you are passing `username` in small whereas you used in webmethod in camelCase i.e `userName`. also use `static` webmethod.

Comment: i am not getting any  error it doesn't reach my BP at the server side

Comment: did you see my update?
the C# code for now is only  int x;  x=6; and i set  a BP on int x;